# don't split verbatim by tables

Tags: floats, verbatim

I have quite long verbatim, which I don't want to be split by table, which is present in source document before verbatim. I have my table wrapped by `\begin{table}[h]`.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the placement specifier: instead of simply `[h]` use `[!hb]` or `[!ht]`. If the problem persists, please add to your question a [minimal working example](http://www.minimalbeispiel.de/mini-en.html) illustrating the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Do not put the verbatim code into a `table` environment. Use

```
\usepackage{caption}
...
\begin{verbatim}
...
\end{verbatim}
\captionof{table}{ ... caption ...}
```